# Verify formalization — Is this the correct first-order definition for a field, and also why is this missing rule needed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

This image is supposed to the first-order definition of a field but when I looked in my textbook (the image is not from the textbook), it seemed to be missing the $0 \neq 1$ part. I never understood why that rule is there to begin with, can someone explain that to me? Also, is there something else wrong in the definition (or missing)?

[image: Definition Image]

Comment: First order definition In which language?  Certainly not first-order predicate logic because you don't have "$\in$" as part of the language, for example.  It seems like you are working inside some axiomatisation of set theory?

Comment: @user10354138 I think the OP means that this is supposed to be an axiomatization of the first-order theory of fields.

Comment: @NoahSchweber is correct. Sorry for the ambiguity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems

- The second line is not associativity,  but *commutativity* (of addition)
- The fourth line has its quantors in wrong order.
- The last line has its quantors is wrong order. And even after swapping them, it  would  accidentally postulates a multiplicative inverse of $0$.
- By leaving out $0\ne 1$, the zero ring "becomes" a field

I am not even happy with the introductory sentences of the definition. I would have preferred

> A set $F$, along with two binary operations $+\colon F\times F\to F$ and $\cdot\colon F\times F\to F$ and two$^1$ designated elements $0,1\in F$ is called a *Field* and denoted as $(F,+,\cdot,0,1)$ **if** it satisfies the following axioms

---

$^1$ adding "distinct" here saves us the $0\ne 1$ axiom